# Configuration of Server root email - Change Address and Name on outgoing email

Tags: postfix

As a newbie Postfix user, I've gotten so far and now I am stuck with a SMALL problem.

I would like to configure my local network servers to send alerts and like using the following:

1. From address: hostname@example.com
2. From name: Hostname

I can get #1 to work fine using `smtp_generic_maps`

The problem is that on my email client, the name is listed as "root" - as in the header shows the following:

```
Date: Sun, 29 Jul 2012 13:21:01 -0400 (EDT)
From: zeus@example.com (root)
To: undisclosed-recipients:;
```

I'd like to change it to **From: zeus@example.com (Zeus)**

I imagine that this can be done in the headers_check, but so far I haven't gotten anything to work and before I waste a ton of time trying to get this to work, I'd like to make sure I am on the right track.

My aliasing and generic_maps are set up correctly (As far as I can see and know - the results are correct!).  I just want to change that last bit in the **From** field to reflect the hostname.

I would also like to add something in the subject of the outgoing messages for easy filtering - something like **Subject: [Zeus.domain] - "Original Subject"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a job for the MTA; it should be done by the mail client.

Postfix is merely reporting the From: header as passed along by the client; in this case, porbably cron thorugh sendmail(1), which sets the friendlyname to the original sender (system user "root")

Why not have each servers' processes send mail to a designated local system account, and then process that and forward it to wherever you want ?

This allows you to modify each machine's outgoing email while avoiding the (unnecessary) mangling of a central MTA.

Comment: Okay - based on your suggestion I changed the friendly name to something more along the lines of what I wanted.  If there was a case which I could not do this and had control, what could I do to "force" this change in the MTA?

Comment: ITYM "had NO control over the clients", because it doesn't make sense otherwise. In that case, you would have to use header_checks.

Comment: I don't have any control over the one daemon sending emails - it seems to be hardcoded to send to the box administrator, which in this case is root.  By changing the friendly name of root to "SERVERNAME" I at least don't have every box with this daemon sending me email from 'root' - instead it shows up as 'SERVERNAME'. -- The minus is that I never actually got header checks to work.  The regex I used functioned fine using other tools on command line, but nothing ever replaced.  I accept your solution because I absolutely agree - mucking about with header_checks is a major PITA for this case.

Comment: But how do I do it....

Answer (score 12):

1. Change e-mail address:

   - vi /etc/postfix/generic

     ```
     root     myname@domain.tld
     ```
   - vi /etc/postfix/main.cf

     ```
     smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
     ```
   - postmap /etc/postfix/generic
   - postfix reload
2. Change name - change name in passwd file from root to My Name:

   - vi /etc/passwd:

     ```
     root:x:0:0:Own Name:/root:/bin/bash
     ```

Comment: The /etc/passwd trick saved me. I already had the generic map done. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks for this.  On my system I had to include the hostname in the generic map:
root@myhost.lan   myname@domaine.tld